# Unable to pass data to servlet using jquery

Tags: java, servlets, jquery

I am developing an application using jquery along with servlets.I have been using jquery theme roller for interface
In my Login.jsp

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#dialog").dialog();
 }); 
 </script>

 <script>
 $("#submit").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type:post,
       url:"LoginServlet.java",
       data:{
       username:$('#username').val(),
       password:$('#password').val() }    
   });   
  });
 </script>

</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
<div id="dialog" title="Login">
<form id="LoginForm" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username"></input><br></br>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="pwd"></input><br></br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" align="middle"></input>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my LoginServlet I check for if the password and username matches and if it matches I am redirecting the user to other page using `response.sendRedirect().`But when I enter the credentials the data is not been passed to the servlet.Also I don get any errors(checked with firebug) or exceptions of any kind...

I am fairly new to jquery as well as java.Where have I gone wrong

I tried `$("#LoginForm").submit(function(){  }` also.Why there are no errors being thrown?? How do I know where am I going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the method type of your ajax call
Instead of this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:post
...
```

should be this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"post",
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try setting:

```
  type: 'POST',
```

eg

```
 <script>
 $("#submit").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url:"LoginServlet.java",
       data:{
       username:$('#username').val(),
       password:$('#password').val() }    
   });   
  });
 </script>
```

And what does firebug say on the request? (http://getfirebug.com/)

**EDIT**

Recreated your javascript and html @ http://jsfiddle.net/qYmkF/

when looking in firebug, i can see the request being fired.

Comment: @netbrain..I tried your solution but no success..The bad part is I am not getting any errors in firebug except for "Reload to activate window console".Once I enter the credentials I stay on the same pg..

Comment: what about the net tab? do you ever see the request getting fired? aha, eureeka. have you set a $('document').ready(function{  }) around the click listener?

Comment: @netbrain..No the request if not getting fired.. The $(document).ready(function() {}) is outside...Its not around the click listener

Comment: I don't think your click listener has ever been registered. So try put the click listener within the ready() block

Comment: @netbrain...I placed my click listener inside the ready()block...But no success...Still stuck with the same error

Comment: take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/qYmkF/ - a recreation of your javascript and html. when looking at firebug, i can definitly see the request when clicking on the button.

Comment: @netbrain...But why is it that my application is not firing the request..??? how to I debug this..I am not understanding anything

Comment: start by inputting the code you have to jsfiddle. and then i can take a look at it.

Comment: @netbrain...I have pasted the code at jsfiddle..you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap code inside a `document.ready`. It wasn't working cause `#submit` button didn't exist yet. So change to this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ //This!!!
    $("#submit").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:"LoginServlet.java",
         data:{
         username:$('#username').val(),
         password:$('#password').val() }    
      });   
    });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried..The request is not getting fired nor any errors I can see in the firebug...

Comment: I tried..The request is not getting fired nor any errors I can see in the firebug...

Comment: could you please, put this code: `alert($("#submit").size());` right before `$("#submit").click(function(){` and tell me the result??

Comment: ..I get a pop up window displaying 1..What does it mean??

Answer (score 0):

Your password id is wrong, change 'password' to 'pwd'

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'LoginServlet.java',
        data:{
            username:$('#username').val(),
            password:$('#pwd').val() 
        }    
   }
);
```